# Jquery foreach set name attribute as value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a [plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) to give my `<select>` elements images loaded by jquery. The thing is, the names are not transferring to the new code, and thus cannot submit the form surrounding it. The new code looks like:

```
<div id="itemselect1" name="item1" class="dd-container">
    <div class="dd-select">
        <input class="dd-selected-value" value="Apple" type="hidden">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="itemselect2" name="item2" class="dd-container">
    <div class="dd-select">
        <input class="dd-selected-value" value="Orange" type="hidden">
    </div>
</div>  // the list continues
```

So I tried this approach to transfer the names over:

```
var list = {
  "itemselect1": "item1",
  "itemselect2": "item2",
  "itemselect3": "item3",
  "itemselect4": "item4",
  "itemselect5": "item5",
  "itemselect6": "item6"
};
$.each( list, function( key, value ) {
  $("#"+ key).children().children("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", value );
});
```

Though it's still not working. The `<input>` elements have no names. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

**Edit:** I've added some changes to help diagnose the problem

```
$.each( list, function( key, value ) {
  $("#"+ key).children().children("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", value );
  console.log(key);
  console.log(value);
  console.log($("div#"+ key).attr("name"));
});
```

Heres what the console says:

```
itemselect1 (index):30
item1 (index):31
undefined (index):32
itemselect2 (index):30
item2 (index):31
undefined (index):32
```

I've tried this at the end of the plugin jquery file as well as in `<script>` tags in the `index` file. It's not finding the name apparently. I'm going to keep digging...

Comment: it looks fine to me - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wa01cmsn/2/ - check whether the input's name attributes are really changed by inspecting the hidden elements

Comment: Your input should have name attribute added as @ArunPJohny stated. You can also replace this
` $("#"+ key).children().children("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", value );`
 with just `$("#"+ key + " input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", value );`  Since you already have the two identifiers at you disposal. no need to call `childer().children()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny It seems to work there, I guess it's clashing with something in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `for in`

```
for (var key in list){
  $("#"+ key).children().children("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", list[key] );
}
```

Comment: OP said the **input** element does not have name

Comment: Ya, i suppose it is interfering with the plugin somehow.